# how can i show multiple data in one string in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have 2 tables in my database one called **topics** and the other called **sections**

every topics has multiple sections and they linked to main topic by id

for example this is my datable

**topics**

```
id
title
content
```

**sections**

```
id
title
topic_id
```

i use this code to show content

```
<?php
$show_topics = $topics->select_topics($page);
while ($rows_topics = mysqli_fetch_array($show_topics [0])) {
    $id_topic       = $rows_topics['id'];
    $title_topic    = $rows_topics['title'];
    $content_topic    = $rows_topics['content'];

    echo $content_topic;

    $select_sections = $topics->view_section_limit($id_topic, 0, 100);

    while ($rows_sections = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sections)) {
        $id_section           = $rows_sections['id'];
        $section_title        = $rows_sections['title'];
        echo $section_title;
    }
}
?>
```

i want to combine all content in one string, i used this code for that

```
<?php
$show_topics = $topics->select_topics($page);
while ($rows_topics = mysqli_fetch_array($show_topics [0])) {
    $id_topic       = $rows_topics['id'];
    $title_topic    = $rows_topics['title'];
    $content_topic    = $rows_topics['content'];
        
    $select_sections = $topics->view_section_limit($id_topic, 0, 100);
    
    while ($rows_sections = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sections)) {
        $id_section           = $rows_sections['id'];
        $section_title        = $rows_sections['title'];
        
        $all_content = $content_topic." ".$section_title;
        echo $all_content;
    }
}
?>
```

but it's duplicate content_topic With all section_title

i want to do that becuse i want to add all section titles to topic contents like that

```
$edit_content = $topics->edit_topic_content($all_content, $id_topic);
```

for example if i have this topics_content

```
topics_content = "this is a beautiful day"
```

and i have 3 sections titles like

```
section 1 title = "camera 1"
section 2 title = "camera 2"
section 3 title = "camera 3"
```

the final data shows like this

> this is a beautiful day camera 1 this is a beautiful day camera 2 this
> is a beautiful day camera 3

i want to make it like this

> this is a beautiful day camera 1 camera 2 camera 3

Comment: Please give a proper example of the exact output you're trying to achieve, it's not very clear what you want or precisely what you think the issue is.

Comment: @ADyson i want to combine all data from topics and section in one string

Comment: Well your code already does that in the `$all_content = $content_topic." ".$section_title;` line, as far as I can see. So what precisely is the problem you want to solve? You mention some duplication but it's not clear what you mean exactly. Again, some sample data would really help to clarify the issue, remember we cannot see your data or your screen.

Comment: PLease, show us an example of the output you want to create, preferably with some examples of the data used to generate that output

Comment: @ADyson 

if i have this `topics_content = "this is a beautiful day"` and i have 3 sections title like `section 1 title = "camera 1"` and `section 2 title = "camera 2"`and `section 3 title = "camera 3"` the final data shows like this `this is a beautiful day camera 1 this is a beautiful day camera 2 this is a beautiful day camera 3` i want to make it like this `this is a beautiful day camera 1 camera 2 camera 3`

Comment: Please [edit] your question with any and all updates of data, code etc, so the info is more readable and the question is complete and coherent. Such info doesn't belong in the comments, they are only for requests for clarification and very brief discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson alrady edited

Comment: Great...now please see the answer below for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a new variable, and append the $content_topic to it only once, during the outer loop, then just add the section titles within the inner loop.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$show_topics = $topics->select_topics($page);

while ($rows_topics = mysqli_fetch_array($show_topics [0]))
{
    $id_topic       = $rows_topics['id'];
    $title_topic    = $rows_topics['title'];
    $content_topic    = $rows_topics['content'];
        
    $select_sections = $topics->view_section_limit($id_topic, 0, 100);

    $all_content = $content_topic;
    
    while ($rows_sections = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sections)) {
        $id_section           = $rows_sections['id'];
        $section_title        = $rows_sections['title'];
        
        $all_content .= " ".$section_title;
    }

    echo $all_content;
}
?>
```

Comment: it's worked but it's skipped first section title

Comment: i don't see how that could be possible to be honest, unless the query is not returning the results properly. What debugging have you done? Remember I can't actually run your database query. Maybe put `var_dump($section_title);` inside the `while ($rows_sections = mysqli_fetch_array($select_sections)) {` so you can see all section titles which are being looped. The code I've modified would always append each one to the all_content string, no matter what.